# Navigate to activity by back button doesn't call onstart()

Tags: android, android-activity, onstart

I have an activity(A) and I need to set some text after activity becomes visible to user ,first time I navigate to activity everything is OK,but when I navigate from (A) to activity (B) and press back button ,it returns to (A) button doesn't call onstart of (A).what is the problem?

Comment: can you please show us some relevant code and logcat entries (if relevant)

Comment: are you sure about that? because as per my knowledge (and the flow you've mentioned) it must call `onRestart`, `onStart` and `onResume` of your activity **A**

Comment: Yeah,I'm sure,in Google document onstart is called when activity becomes visible to user

Answer (score 1):

Back button is navigation to previous activity in activity stack, which is already created and thus its onResume method will be called. So you can do what you want inside onResume().

If it is must for your activity to create new instance do as follows:
If you are on activity A and going B, call A.finish() so it discards A from activity stack, and on B override backPressed and create a new instance of A.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Intent i= new Intent(this, A.class);
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   this.finish();
   startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: pressing back button on activity B will provoke onRestart and onStart on activity A. What you've suggested is something different than the problem

Comment: onstart is called when activity becomes visible to user and after that if it exists in stack onresume is called